# Is it possible to take multiple tabs out of Safari into a new window?

Tags: macos, safari

On macOS Safari, you can create a new Safari window by dragging a tab out of the tab bar.

On Chrome across platforms, you can command (or control) click on tabs to select multiple tabs, and then when you drag out a tab it will create a new window with tabs.

I like this feature of Chrome and always try to do it in Safari. However, command clicking tabs does not select multiple tabs. Is there any way to take multiple tabs from a Safari window and convert them into a new window?

Comment: Have you tried to see if you can with AppleScript? All within a `tell app "Safari"` block: make a new window with `tell (make new document) to if it exists then set W to the front window`. Then, in theory, you might be able to `move (every tab of window 2 whose URL contains "twitter.com") to the front window`. May not work; or may need tweaking. If it does, there's scope for some nifty ways to implement this.

Comment: Good idea—thanks for the starting point. I'll try tinkering with it sometime

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54089865/20307768

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to somewhat replicate the functionality with workaround but this can be considered as a clumsy and non-intuitive way.

It takes advantage on pinning pages. In general terms:

- pin needed tabs
- open new Safari window
- unpin tabs

In order to make it simpler to use from keyboard one can define shortcut to toggle pinning i.e. two operations with same shortcut: `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App shortcuts`, app Safari, one for 'Pin Tab' and another for 'Unpin Tab', assign same keyboard shortcut (for example <kbd>⌥⌘P</kbd>).

Possible workflow from keyboard:

- navigate between Safari tabs using <kbd>⌃⇥</kbd> (Control-Tab)
- pin needed tabs with keyboard shortcut (for example <kbd>⌥⌘P</kbd>),
- when all needed tabs are pinned open new Safari window with <kbd>⌘N</kbd>,
- go through all pinned tabs using <kbd>⌃⇥</kbd> and unpin them using shortcut.

Comment: Despite being a workaround this actually seems to be the easiest way, so I'm going to mark this as answering the question.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot do that in one go with Safari like you can in Chrome. You have to first drag out one tab to make a new window, and then manually drag each following tab to that new window.

Comment: Ah, that's a pity given how often I find myself doing this (I use different windows to organize tabs into different "workspaces")